# Algorithm for returning a random number from a stream of numbers

Tags: probability

Given the following premises:

- You have a stream of numbers from which you can read one number at a time.
- You only have enough space to store one number.
- After processing the entire stream, you have to return a random number from the stream.
- The probability of picking any number in the stream should be equal.

Proposed algorithm:

1. Receive the first number and stored it as the random value (since a stream with only 1 number should return that number a 100% of the times)
2. Receive the second number and using a random of (1,2), store either first number or second number. Giving you a 1/2 of probability you keep the result of the first iteration and 1/2 you will replace it with the second number.
3. Receive the third number, since you only have the result for the second iteration only, you do a random (1,2,3), {1,2} represent the result of the previous iteration, while 3 means you will store the 3rd number instead. Giving you a 2/3 of probability you keep the number of the second iteration and 1/3 you will replace it with the third number.
4. Receive the 4th number, like step 3 you now do a random of 4 and a result of  4 means you will store the 4th number. Giving you a 3/4 of probability you keep the number of the third iteration and 1/4 you will replace it with the 4th number.
5. Receive the nth number in iteration X, do a random using X numbers, replacing the result with the nth number if the random number is X. Giving you a (X-1)/X probability that you keep the number from the previous iteration and a 1/X probability you will replace it with the nth number.

Would this algorithm still hold the premise of "The probability of picking any number in the stream should be equal"?

Comment: Well, is your system allowed to remember which stage it's on?   If so then this makes sense (I didn't check the arithmetic, but it's clear that something close to this has to be correct).  If the machine can't know what stage it's on, then it does not sound possible.

Comment: @lulu If by stage you mean the number of numbers read so far, yes it does remember it.

Comment: That's what I meant, yes.

Comment: Thanks. Would the probability still be 1/n for each number? If you want to elaborate or add something in the answer, I can mark it as the answer

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.  Seems to work perfectly, and the posted solution, from @TonyK , seems to be a complete proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your step-by-step description of the algorithm makes it clear that it works as you designed it. For the $i^\text{th}$ number to be chosen, we require two things:

1. at step $i$, the random number generated is $i$ (with a probability of $1/i$);
2. at step $j$ with $j>i$, the random number generated is not $j$ (with a probability of $(j-1)/j$).

The total probability of choosing the $i^\text{th}$ number is thus $\frac{1}{i}\frac{i}{i+1}\frac{i+1}{i+2}\cdots\frac{n-1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}$, as required.